# Is it possible to iterate through all storage folders and download all image urls to a list/file?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have been struggling to figure out how to download all image urls we have in one of our buckets. I am able to download urls one by one using a python blob script but I can't seem to iterate through all folders to print out the urls.

I am 94% sure I have all permissions set correctly.

Any help would be super appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask There are many guides and tutorials published by Google and others to show you the basics.

Comment: List the blobs, iterate on the list and download them one by one. I don't see the problem!